# Using Outlook VBA to forward Emails, but want exclude appointments

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I managed to find a nice little script that will forward emails to an external address becuase our exchange server is configured not to do that.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim varEntryIDs
    Dim objItem
    Dim i As Integer
    varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
        Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))
        Set myItem = objItem.Forward
        myItem.Recipients.Add "mike.dumka@outlook.com"
        myItem.Send
    Next
End Sub
```

Works perfect. But now ... I would only like to do this if they are messages, not appointment updates or requests. I have no idea where to find this, or even what to look for. My VBA skills are from very long ago.

If you look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U28SD.jpg), I think I have the MsgBox function in the right way, but could you verify?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little bit of conditional logic to ensure that you're only dealing with `MailItem` (since `objItem` is variant/object and may be another *type* of item like an `AppointmentItem`, etc.):

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

    MsgBox "I'm working!", vbExclamation

    Dim varEntryIDs
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim i As Integer
    varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
        Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))

        '## Check the item's TypeName and ONLY process if it's a MailItem:

        If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then

            Set myItem = objItem.Forward
            myItem.Recipients.Add "mike.dumka@outlook.com"
            myItem.Send

        Else:
            MsgBox "Type of item is: " & TypeName(objItem)

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this is dumb, but now it does nothing. i copy and pasted exactly what was there. Is there any way to test and see if it is running?

Comment: You don't know how to put a MessageBox prompt in the code to test if it's working?  Revised above which will A) show you that it's working and B) message box if **any** type other than `MailItem` is received, so that you can see what is coming in...

Comment: Sorry, my response got deleted for being an answer, not a comment. I needed to attach a screenshot to show you why it was not working. But here is a link to what the VBA code looks like. and it is still not working. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgxbpsnoe2t9lsi/Screenshot%202014-07-09%2013.16.41.png

Comment: Looks OK for the first message box. So do you ever see the message box when Outlook is open?

Comment: No ... nothing. It is like something has just stopped. I even tried to paste my original function back in, and nothing. Could I have broken a security setting somewhere?

Comment: I can't answer that. Test it by sending yourself an email. You should get the messagebox if your function is working and macros are enabled. You said previously that your code "worked perfectly". All you've done so far is is to add a MsgBox prompt. If your code *was* working as you describe, it still should be working with this minor addition.

Comment: Your never going to believe this, but security was stopping from everything. Did some digging, changed the settings, restarted outlook and boom, there goes the dynamite. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Ahh yeah if you have macros disabled then that would certainly be a problem. Glad it works now!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either check the myItem.MessageClass property (it will be "IPM.Note" for the regular messages) or myItem.Class property - it will be 43 (olMail).